# How can I return multiple rows from a python function to a pandas dataframe using apply?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a defined function to query a REST API which returns multiple rows per request from a pandas dataframe using apply. It looks like what I have so far is running the function correctly but because the for loop returns more than one row I only get the last one.

What I want to do is return multiple rows for each row I pass to the function.

This is my function I'm using:

```
def get_entity_rec(row):
try:
    documents = row.content
    textcon = row.content[0:2000]
    doclang = [textcon]
    outputs = []
    result = client.recognize_entities(documents = doclang)[0]
    entitylength = len(result)
    for entity in result.entities:
            row['text'] = entity.text
            row['category'] = entity.category
            row['subcategory'] = entity.subcategory
    return row
except Exception as err:
    print("Encountered exception. {}".format(err))
```

And my code where I apply it:

```
apandas3 = apandas2.apply(get_entity_rec, axis=1)
```

I get (what i think is) the last result like this:

| path | text | category | subcategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| path of file | i am text | i am the category returned | i am the subcategory returned |

I want to return a dataframe with the original columns repeated with each "entity" returned by the function lke this:

| path | text | category | subcategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| path of file | i am text | i am the category returned | i am the subcategory returned |
| path of file | i am text | i am the first category returned | i am the first subcategory returned |
| path of file | i am text | i am the second category returned | i am the second subcategory returned |

Comment: Have you noticed how rare is ID of your question? Look into [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444444/how-can-i-return-multiple-rows-from-a-python-function-to-a-pandas-dataframe-usin/). You have id 66444444, six times four, how rare! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` when applied rows can only use a function that returns one row

To achieve what you want, you can stick your categories/subcategories into a `list` that is stored in a row, and then `explode`. Let me demonstrate. Since your code is not self-contained to run (please review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before your next post!), here is an example that hopefully explains the idea

```
# create an example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'path':['A','B','C'], 'text' : ['cat1A subcat1A cat2A subcat2A','cat1B subcat1B cat2B subcat2B', 'cat1C subcat1C cat2C subcat2C']})

# define our processing function
def get_entity_rec(row):
    text = row['text']
    tokens = text.split() # simulated processing
    categories = [tokens[0], tokens[2]] # note how we stick them in a list
    subcategories = [tokens[1], tokens[3]] # note how we stick them in a list
    row['cat'] = categories
    row['subcat'] = subcategories
    return row
```

Here we create a simple df and a processing function that needs to return multiple rows per each return row. But since that is not allowed for the `apply` function, it returns *one* row where the multiple values are stored as *lists*

when we apply this function to the df

```
df.apply(get_entity_rec, axis=1)
```

we obtain this

```
    path    text                            cat             subcat
0   A       cat1A subcat1A cat2A subcat2A   [cat1A, cat2A]  [subcat1A, subcat2A]
1   B       cat1B subcat1B cat2B subcat2B   [cat1B, cat2B]  [subcat1B, subcat2B]
2   C       cat1C subcat1C cat2C subcat2C   [cat1C, cat2C]  [subcat1C, subcat2C]
```

note how categories and subcategories are in lists inside the df

Now we can `explode` our columns -- since we want to explode `cat` and `subcat` in parallel, here is how we do it:

```
df.apply(get_entity_rec, axis=1).apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

to obtain

```
 path   text                            cat     subcat
0   A   cat1A subcat1A cat2A subcat2A   cat1A   subcat1A
0   A   cat1A subcat1A cat2A subcat2A   cat2A   subcat2A
1   B   cat1B subcat1B cat2B subcat2B   cat1B   subcat1B
1   B   cat1B subcat1B cat2B subcat2B   cat2B   subcat2B
2   C   cat1C subcat1C cat2C subcat2C   cat1C   subcat1C
2   C   cat1C subcat1C cat2C subcat2C   cat2C   subcat2C
```

Comment: thanks, this is great. Is there a way to split the cat/subcat list across columns instead of rows?

Comment: glad it helped. yes there is. I personally usually use smth like df['cat'].apply(pd.Series) but lots more ways are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns/35491399